# Rails form_authenticity_token not regenerating after POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, csrf, authenticity-token

I was under the impression that Rails will regenerate the `form_authenticity_token` after any POST, PUT, or DELETE action. But for some reason, after a successful POST to the users resource the `form_authenticity_token` does not regenerate. I'm free to POST as many time as I would like with the same CSRF token over and over.

I've got a namespaced API and I'm using the RABL gem to build out my responses. This is how I have everything setup...

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    render "show", :status => (@user.save ? :ok : :unprocessable_entity)
  end
  ...
end

class Api::V1::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  layout '/api/v1/layouts/application.json.erb'
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  ...
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

The post goes through fine, there are no errors or warning in the development.log or in the consoled `$ rails s` log.

I've check `verified_request?` from within the `create` method and it's returning true. I've removed the render and setup a `create.json.rabl` view with the same code as the `show.json.rabl` view... no dice.

I'm running Rails 3.1.3 w/ Ruby 1.9.2p290 w/ a cookie session store.

The authenticity token is being sent via request header (X-CSRF-Token)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were under the wrong impressions. As you can see from the relevant bit of the [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L101) the form authenticity token stays the same for the lifetime of the session.